# java script code to display my login and sign page as a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is script for the login and signup portal of my website and it is shown when someone mouseover on login link in header, how can I open it as a popup window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".welcome").mouseover(function() {
            $("#sign_box").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#sign_box").show();


        });

        $("#sign_box").live("mouseleave", function() {
            $("#sign_box").hide();
        });
    });
</script> -->

<style type="text/css">
    #sign_box {
        width: 400px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: solid 1px #5ea0c1;
        padding: 8px;
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        text-align: left;
        z-index: 1100;
    }
</style>
```

After some searches I found a javascript code to display signup and login window as a popup window but I am unable to understand how to apply it to my div id named sign_box

```
function displayPopup(params) {
    var pageid = 1;
    var pageObj = Runner.pages.PageManager.getById(pageid);
    args = {
        bodyContent: "<iframe frameborder='0' id='popupIframe" + pageid + "' style='width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0;'></iframe>",
        footerContent: "<span>&nbsp;</span>",
        headerContent: params.headerContent,
        centered: true,
        render: true,
        width: params.width ? params.width : 450,
        height: params.height ? params.height : 315
    },
    afterCreateHandler = function (win) {
        var bodyNode = $(win.bodyNode.getDOMNode()),
            iframeNode = $("iframe#popupIframe" + pageid, bodyNode);

        iframeNode.load(function () {
            if (Runner.isChrome) {
                bodyNode.addClass("noScrollBar");
            }
            win.show();

        }).attr("src", params.url);
    },
    afterCloseHandler = params.afterClose;

    if (Runner.isChrome) {
        $("< style type='text/css'> .yui3-widget-bd::-webkit-scrollbar {display:none;} < /style>").appendTo("head");
    }

    Runner.pages.PageManager.createFlyWin.call(pageObj, args, true,
    afterCreateHandler, afterCloseHandler);
}

function login() {

    params = {
        url: 'login.php',
        afterClose: function (win) {
            win.destroy(true);
        },
        headerContent: 'Login'
    };
    displayPopup(params);
}
```

Comment: Just remove live with on event.

Comment: window.open(url,name,features) for more visit the below page
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a popup like a new window through javascript, latest browsers will block this automatically and will ask the users permission to open this. This will cause users to find it hard to find the login sometimes.

You can use http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Or do you mean like this? The live event is no longer supported though and is not needed in this case.

Used @oMiKeY's answer with some updates based on comments.

```js
$('.loginbutton').on('click', function() {
  $('#dialog').addClass('shown');
  $('#dialog').dialog();
});
```

```css
#dialog {
  display: none;
}
#dialog.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" class="loginbutton" value="login">
  <a href="#" class="loginbutton">login</a>
  <div id="dialog" title="Sign-in">

    <input type="text" name="login" id="login" placeholder="Enter Username" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I found some code on a website to display login and signup as a popup window but I am unable to understand how to apply it at a particular div id as I have in my code sign_box

Comment: @sandal Can you provide the URL of the site?

Comment: This is the link of the website and I want my login and signup page with the same same functionality they explain...                  http://xlinesoft.com/blog/2013/04/25/displaying-a-page-in-a-popup-window/comment-page-1/#comment-9801

Comment: @sandal maybe jquery ui can lend a hand? https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default . You can put an Iframe inside the dialog or something else.

Comment: Could anybody can explain how can I use the code of website link http://xlinesoft.com/blog/2013/04/25/displaying-a-page-in-a-popup-window/comment-page-1/#comment-9801 to my website for login and signup pop up.

Comment: @sandal From what I can understand you require xlinesoft.com/phprunner to use half the Javascript in there. Why do you want to use that script exactly? Is it because it loads an iframe inside the popup? –  I have updated my example in my post a little. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I say stick with the standard jQuery dialog boxes: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

They are super easy to implement and modify, and have a great look; Plus they are draggable and auto-center in the screen. Try this out:

```html
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="dialog" title="Sign-in">
    <input type="text" name="login" id="login" placeholder="Enter Username" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/pmspohkL/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".welcome").mouseover(function() {
         $("#sign_box").fadeIn("slow");
         $("#sign_box").show();
     });
     $("#sign_box").on("mouseleave", function() {
         $("#sign_box").hide();
     });
 });
```

> using window.open() function

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
        $(".welcome").mouseover(function() {
            var newWindow =         window.open('http://google.com');
            $("#sign_box").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#sign_box").show();
        });

        $("#sign_box").on("mouseleave", function() {
            $("#sign_box").hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: In the demo you show me how to hover sign_box id when mouseover on welcome but I want to know how to popup sign_box div as a new window.

Comment: @sandal, If you need to show the #sign_box content in new window, create a seperate file for the same and with the use of     window.open('YourFilePath') function call that file.

Comment: Not in a new window but just want to display a popup for login and signup when clicking on login or signup